# Make My Form and Image Background Fluid

Tags: css

I do have a Optin form created in my Homepage. 
But when i scale the browser down, the text fields and background images doesn't get smaller.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="jpl-ebook">
  <div class="jpl-form">
    <form>
      <table width="220">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Name:</b></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Email:</b></td>
            <td><input type="email" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input id="bigbutton" type="submit" value="GET INSTANT ACCESS!" /></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
.jpl-ebook {
    width: 90%;
    height: 350px;
    background: url(images/extras/book.png) no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
.jpl-form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 170px;
    left: 190px;
}
```

The image background has 490 x 350 pixels.

Comment: The `<table width="220">` is bad. `width` is a deprecated attribute; you should really use CSS for that, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scale the background image supplied in CSS, use the [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) property. You'll probably want

```
.jpl-ebook {
  background-size:contain;
}
```

As for text fields, conventionally you don't scale these. You *can* scale the width quite easily, relative to the field's parent, by providing a percentage width viz `width:40%`. The input's height is determined by the CSS [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-size); this property accepts relative values, but that's relative to *text* size, not *container* size.

Depending on how you want to change the size of text fields to change, javascript might be necessary.